# Adding scrip to export python result from json to excel or csv file

Tags: python, json, csv

I am new to the Python world so apologies. I am looking into a set of time series I have downloaded from an API. These data have been printed as JSON file (as seen in the below code). However, how can I convert this data from JSON to EXCEL or CSV?

**Below is what I used:**

```py
import requests
payload = "{\"startDate\": 20190930, \"endDate\": 20191018, \"tags\":[\"PAYMENT.REIMBURSEMENT.1Y.BLOOMBERG\"]}"
headers = {
'content-type': "application/json",
'accept': "application/json",
'authorization': "Bearer AAIkOWNmNGVjMzctYTg5MC00YjhiLWE4MTEtNmE4ZDUzMzU1OWVlGUDsir"
}
proxyDict = {"http": "http://webproxy.payment.nsroot.net:8080/", "https": "http://payment.nsroot.net:8080/"}
r = requests.post(url="https://payment.com/data?client_id=9cf4ec37-a890-4b8b-a811-6a8d533559ee", data=payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
print(r.json())
```

**Below is the result that the above code is providing.**

{'frequency': 'DAILY', 'body': {'PAYMENT.REIMBURSEMENT.1Y.BLOOMBERG': {'x': [20190930, 20191001, 20191002, 20191003, 20191004, 20191007, 20191008, 20191009, 20191010, 20191011, 20191014, 20191015, 20191016, 20191017, 20191018], 'c':[ [60.0392, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.0391, 60.039, 60.039, 60.039, 60.039]][1], 'type': 'SERIES'}}, 'status': 'OK'}

**Can you let me know how to convert that to csv file? Where Column A is the Date in (yyyymmdd) and Column B are the Values like the below**>

**Dates      Values**
20190930   60.0392
...
...
20191018   60.039

Thank you.

Comment: Share the returned JSON please and an example of the desired CSV data.

Comment: Hi @balderman, below is the result as per printing.{'frequency': 'DAILY', 'body': {'PAYMENT.REIMBURSEMENT.1Y.BLOOMBERG': {'x': [20190930, 20191001, 20191002, 20191003, 20191004, 20191007, 20191008, 20191009, 20191010, 20191011, 20191014, 20191015, 20191016, 20191017, 20191018], 'c': [37.5601, 37.5601, 37.5602, 37.5601, 37.5601, 37.56, 37.56, 37.56, 37.56, 37.56, 37.5599, 37.5599, 37.5598, 37.5598, 37.5597], 'type': 'SERIES'}}, 'status': 'OK'}

Comment: For CSV file, I am looking into saving it a format like: Column A (Date), Column B (Values) with sheet name as PAYMENT.REIMBURSEMENT.1Y.BLOOMBERG

Comment: Hi All, i have updated my question so it will be more clear to everyone. Hoping for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = list(zip(test['body']['PAYMENT.REIMBURSEMENT.1Y.BLOOMBERG']['x'], test['body']['PAYMENT.REIMBURSEMENT.1Y.BLOOMBERG']['c']))

import csv
with open('PAYMENT.REIMBURSEMENT.1Y.BLOOMBERG', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Date', 'values']
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for row in result:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

if you need to convert to excel with sheet name following is the code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Date', 'values'])

df.to_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='PAYMENT.REIMBURSEMENT.1Y.BLOOMBERG', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a path to you desktop, and put it in a constant (conventionally noted in UPPER_CASE):

```
import pathlib

DESKTOP_PATH = pathlib.Path('/Users/user_name/Desktop')
```

Iterate over the key and values in you json's body, as per your request, the key is used as the file name, which is why it is held in a variable by that name, and the values are the dictionary holding the csv data:

```
for file_name, data in r.json()['body']:
    csv_rows = '\n'.join(','.join(values) for values in zip(*data.values()))
    (DESKTOP_PATH / filename).write_text(f'{",".join(data.keys())}\n{csv_rows}')
```

Inside the for loop, we build the csv corresponding to each file: `zip(*data.values())` converts the values list, which holds a list of lists in the form of `[column_a_values, column_b_values, ...]`, to an iterator which combines all the elements on the same row. i.e. `list(zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]))` equals `[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]`.

We then join all the values in a row by with a comma by using `','.join(values)` and join the rows with new lines between them by using `'\n'.join(...)`.

Finally, we write all that text in one go using write_text on a concatenation of the desktop path and the filename given by `DESKTOP_PATH / filename`, and the final text is  given by `f'{",".join(data.keys())}\n{csv_rows}'` which first outputs the column names, and then the rows we have calculated above.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: @borchvm Sorry, I thought my code was self explanatory... Is it clear enough now?

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality, now it is clearer, thanks @feature_engineer